# Next JS: Import an html file to component prior to exporting project as static HTML

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm currently using `next export` to create pre-rendered HTMLs. The issue i'm facing is that I need to import an existing header HTML file into my component prior to the export. This header HTML file is also located in a directory not relative to my dist folder.

So let's say my dist files are in this sub-directory:
`www.mysite.com/myproject/`

And the header I need to import is located here:
`www.mysite.com/htmls/nav/header.html`

Is there a way to import and show this `header.html` prior to exporting it as a static html page? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to accomplish your goal:

Using Javascript

```
<script>
function includeHeader() {
  var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
  /*loop through a collection of all HTML elements:*/
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    elmnt = z[i];
    /*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
    file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
    if (file) {
      /*make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name:*/
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
          if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
          if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
          /*remove the attribute, and call this function once more:*/
          elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
          includeHTML();
        }
      } 
      xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
      xhttp.send();
      /*exit the function:*/
      return;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Then call it

```
<script>
   includeHeader();
</script>
```

Using HTML

```
<div w3-include-html="/htmls/nav/header.html"></div>
```